# Change dot Nav color by Item Number

Tags: html, css, html-lists, menuitem

See the below picture to understand what i mean :)

[image]

```
  <ul class="uk-dotnav uk-flex-center">
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="0" class="uk-active"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="1"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="2"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="3"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Code from widgetkit i cant change it. 

 Is it possible to change the color from dot for each item ? (maybe with css or script?)

Thanks ! picknstick.de/t-shirt-s

---

If i use your Code ovokuro , then i got this problem:
[image]
any solution´s for this ?

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the default bullet with a `pseudoelement` and style each `li` as you like

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li:before {
  content: '●';
  padding-right: .5em;
}

li[data-uk-slideshow-item="1"]:before {
  color: red;
}

li[data-uk-slideshow-item="2"]:before {
  color: blue;
}

li[data-uk-slideshow-item="3"]:before {
  color: orange;
}

li[data-uk-slideshow-item="4"]:before {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-uk-slideshow-item="1"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
  <li data-uk-slideshow-item="2"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
  <li data-uk-slideshow-item="3"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
  <li data-uk-slideshow-item="4"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay that works but now i got some other problems :/ if i use your code

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAeQM.png

any solution´s for this ?

Comment: The issue is that the existing bullets won't hide? You'll need to use dev tools and inspect where they're coming from. Or if the bullet is appearing before all list items you'll need to be more specific with the list you're targetting. There may be a class or id attached to the `ul` that you can use

Comment: `<ul class="uk-dotnav uk-flex-center">
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="0" class="uk-active"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="1"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="2"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
    <li data-uk-slideshow-item="3"><a href="#">Love Always Wins !</a></li>
</ul>`


Here i got the class from`ul`

Answer (score 0):

```
.uk-dotnav ul li a{
  list-style: none;
}

.uk-dotnav   li:before {
  content: '●';
  padding-right: .5em;
  font-size:26px;
}

.uk-dotnav   li[data-uk-slideshow-item="1"]:before  {
  color: red;
}

.uk-dotnav   li[data-uk-slideshow-item="2"]:before {
  color: blue;
}

.uk-dotnav   li[data-uk-slideshow-item="3"]:before {
  color: orange;
}

.uk-dotnav    li[data-uk-slideshow-item="4"]:before {
  color: green;
}
```

Something like that ?